# cheeriojs parsing issue : cannot find <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

### Background

I'm parsing a HTML page using [cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) inside my NodeJs application. 
The objective is to obtain an array of links from that page.

### Problem

The library works well, but I have a problem with a specific set of tags (two `<a>` tags) that **cheerio** won't recognize for the love of my life!

```
<a href="/wiki/Orokin_Void" title="Orokin Void" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Void</a> <a href="/wiki/Storage_Containers" title="Storage Containers" class="mw-redirect">Containers</a>
```

I checked and double checked to see if the tags were ideally structured

So, according tot the documentation, the following code would print `2`:

```
let htmlSource = '<a href="/wiki/Orokin_Void" title="Orokin Void" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Void</a> <a href="/wiki/Storage_Containers" title="Storage Containers" class="mw-redirect">Containers</a>';
let cheerioStuff = $(htmlSource).find("a").length;
console.print(cheerioStuff);
```

Instead, it prints `0`. Which is mesmerizing, at least for me. The same issue seems to appear with another string `Corpus T3 <a href="/wiki/Defense" title="Defense">Defense</a> Reward`.

However, it works with the following one:

`<div class="pi-data-value pi-font"><a href="/wiki/Orokin_Vault" title="Orokin Vault" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Vault</a></div>`

or this one:

`<a href="/wiki/Lynx_Osprey" title="Lynx Osprey">Lynx Osprey</a>`

### Question

At this point it's probably possible that ::

1. I have special invisible evil characters in the HTML source that cheerio doesn't like.
2. cheerio will only find `<a>` tags within other tags, or if they are alone.

I already tested the first option but the results didn't change. So right now I am inclined to believe the issue is the second option, which I find extremely limiting.

It can also be a combinaison of the both, in which case I am royally screwed.

How can I make this work? Any suggestions?

Comment: Another possibility: it won't work if the piece of HTML has no root tag. Have you tried to wrap those <a> within a <div>, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` looks for *descendants* of the elements in the current set, but your `a` elements aren't descendants, they *are* the current set (e.g., the top level). You'd want `filter`:

```
let cheerioStuff = $(htmlSource).filter("a").length;
```

...or possibly a combination of `filter` and `find` if you want to cover both bases:

```
let elements = $(htmlSource);
let cheerioStuff = elements.find("a").add(elements.filter("a")).length;
```

For instance, this outputs `2`:

```
"use strict";
let $ = require('cheerio');

let htmlSource = '<a href="/wiki/Orokin_Void" title="Orokin Void" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Void</a> <a href="/wiki/Storage_Containers" title="Storage Containers" class="mw-redirect">Containers</a>';
let elements = $(htmlSource);
let cheerioStuff = elements.find("a").add(elements.filter("a")).length;
console.log(cheerioStuff);
```

...whereas this:

```
"use strict";
let $ = require('cheerio');

let htmlSource = '<div><a href="/wiki/Orokin_Void" title="Orokin Void" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Void</a></div> <a href="/wiki/Orokin_Void" title="Orokin Void" class="mw-redirect">Orokin Void</a> <a href="/wiki/Storage_Containers" title="Storage Containers" class="mw-redirect">Containers</a>';
let elements = $(htmlSource);
console.log("find: " + elements.find("a").length);
console.log("filter " + elements.filter("a").length);
console.log("combined: " + elements.find("a").add(elements.filter("a")).length);
```

...outputs:

```
find: 1
filter 2
combined: 3
```

...because I've added one inside a `div`.